# Why I can not ping google.com when I connect to an embedded system via ahoc wifi

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, internet, wireless-router, ad-hoc-network

I have two wifi device on my laptop.

I use on of them to connect to internet via a router. Its IP is 10.0.1.98 (router IP is 10.0.1.1)

In this case I can connect to any web site and in general internet connection works well.

Now I am trying to connect to an embedded system via the other wifi device in ad-hoc mode.

I can connect to other device and my second interface has ip (10.0.0.121) default gate way is 10.0.52 (my device IP)

Now I can not connect to internet (first wifi is still connected and has the same IP)

If I try to ping google.com, I am getting time out (it detects goggle ip correctly, but can not connect to it)

Why I can not use internet when my second wifi is connected to an adhoc network?

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that this issue is because windows prefers the 2nd WiFi over the other, then you might need to manually raise the metric of the 2nd WiFi interface, so that Windows will not prefer it as the default interface for internet access.

Check : How to select default network interface for internet?

Check windows site : http://support.microsoft.com/kb/299540

Comment: I changed the interface metrics and it fixed the problem. Is there a way that I can add setting in my embedded device that it changes metrics on my pc, when my PC connects to the embedded device via adhoc wifi?